# Simple PHP application to create URL's like <ROOT_URL>/twitter_username

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, twitter

I am making a simple php application which uses twitter to login as shown in the example here at http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/
However, instead of going to a page where the user posts a tweet, I want to redirect the user to a URL /twitter_user_name where he can see his twitter profile information.
 Also, this page needs to be publicly viewable at /twitter_user_name as the profile page of the person. I am not sure how I can create URL's like /twitter_user_name.
I am not using any framework as such.

My DB structure for the users table is:

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `oauth_uid` text,
    `oauth_token` text,
    `oauth_secret` text,
    `is_logged_in` boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How do I accomplish this without using any framework?

Comment: That's a job for .htacces and mod_rewrite ;)

Comment: Please suggest how to accomplish using .htacces. Right now it goes to update.php as can be seen in the code

Comment: Just look at the related links on the right, I see at least 3 that will help -->

Answer (score 2):

Simple, use `mod_rewrite` in a `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^twitter_(.*)$ twitter_profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

`twitter_profile.php` will be called with `GET` param (username) as `$1`

You can learn about `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` [here](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite).

Comment: Or if you want something like `/twitter/user`: `RewriteRule ^twitter/(.+)$ update.php?twitter_user=$1 [L]`

Comment: Will these create permanent URL's to the user's show page, which can be seen publicly.

Comment: Yes, as long as twitter_user.php exists and .htaccess exists they're permanent